# JavaScript arrays declaration ways difference

Tags: javascript, arrays

This could be a pretty basic question, in JavaScript, what's difference between:

```
var userDetails = {};  
var usersList = [];
```

I was reading an article which had following code:

```
 function GetSampleUsersList() {  
    var userDetails = {};  
    var usersList = [];  
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {  
        userDetails["UserId"] = i;  
        userDetails["UserName"] = "User- " + i;  
        userDetails["Company"] = "Company- " + i;  
        usersList.push(userDetails);  
    }  
    return JSON.stringify(usersList);  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `userDetails = {}` is not an array and `userDetails["UserId"]` is just a bracket notation of accessing object's property

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty basic question.

```
var o = {}
```

initializes an empty object. Then you assign its properties.

```
 var a = []
```

initializes an empty array. You then add the newly created object to the array

```
a.push( o );
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using for every iteration the same `userDetails`, because you overwrite just the properties and while you have pushed the same object, you have always the same content for every element in the array.

```js
 function GetSampleUsersList() {  
    var userDetails = {};
    var usersList = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        userDetails["UserId"] = i;
        userDetails["UserName"] = "User- " + i;
        userDetails["Company"] = "Company- " + i;
        usersList.push(userDetails);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(usersList);
}

console.log(GetSampleUsersList());
```

Better use a **new** empty object for every loop.

```js
 function GetSampleUsersList() {  
    var userDetails;
    var usersList = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        userDetails = {}; // this is necessary
        userDetails["UserId"] = i;
        userDetails["UserName"] = "User- " + i;
        userDetails["Company"] = "Company- " + i;
        usersList.push(userDetails);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(usersList);
}
console.log(GetSampleUsersList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var userDetails = {}; -- object notation in javascript
 var usersList = [];  is an array notation in javascript.
```

for more infomation refer here http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetSampleUsersList() {      
var userDetails = {};  //created an empty object userDetails 
var usersList = [];  //created an empty array userDetails
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {  //looping to add property and value in object and for each iteration object is getting pushed into array at an index i.
    userDetails["UserId"] = i;  
    userDetails["UserName"] = "User- " + i;  
    userDetails["Company"] = "Company- " + i;  
    usersList.push(userDetails);  // pushing object {"UserId":i, "UserName":"User-i", "Company":"Company-i"} into array
}  
    return JSON.stringify(usersList);  // Parsing the object into javascript string
}
```